# Lotus Sametime web service API

Tags: rest, soap, lotus, sametime

Is there a SOAP or REST API for Sametime to enable an application to push presence information on behalf of all Sametime users, and to subscribe or poll, the users' presence information?
Where can I find information about it?

Answer (score 3):

With Sametime 8.5 and later IBM offers the Sametime Proxy Server.  The Proxy server has a REST API, but you will not be able to do anything with it, unless your application authenticates as a user.

You could do what you want, if you built a little SOAP interface using the Sametime Community Server toolkit however, this will give you low level access to the server, and will not require you to login as a user, and allows you to light login as a user to change their status.

Carl

[www.epilio.com](http://www.epilio.com)

Answer (score -1):

You might want to ask that on the [Atom protocol ML](http://www.imc.org/atom-protocol/). IIRC [James Snell](http://www.snellspace.com) worked on "Atom for Lotus" a while ago.

Comment: External referencing without useful resource.